# Have a Full Screen Width Background in a responsive grid site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a Responsive grid site for a client (a modified version of WP responsive theme), and they have a slideshow on the homepage with a main page that has a background that they want to extend the full width of the page/viewport overtop of the main background.

Currently I have this

```
#slideshow{
    position: relative;
}
#slideshow:before {
    content:"";
    width:8000px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('images/bground-tiled.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    left:-3530px;
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow:
        inset 0px 15px 8px -10px #222,
        inset 0px -15px 8px -10px #222;
}
```

which works fine on a desktop but on mobile/tablet it shows the screen as 8000px wide with extending out to the right due to the margin. I need a solution that does not "ruin" mobile views in this manner

I also just want to know the proper way to accomplish this for future reference. The content is in a 960px container and I cannot rework the entire design of the site to have an outside 100% div on the slider section with an inner div that is 960px (unfortunately).

here is a crudely drawn example
[image]

**EDIT: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7s44S/14/**

Comment: Can you institute media queries within WordPress?

Comment: yes i have some in place not related to this such as @media screen and (max-width: 980px){
 #top-widget{
  margin-top:2% !important;
 }
}

Comment: Okay, I was curious about that. What do you mean by "shows the screen as 8000px wide with extending out to the right due to the margin"? Have you tried `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: Did you set any viewport in your head, like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: on mobile it shows as if my entire page is meant to be 8000px wide (due to the :before css) with all the content being on the left side of the screen in a 960px container (looks very small, because it is 'zoomed out'). however on desktop it looks like normal ...so hard to put into words

Comment: overflow hidden has no effect and yes the viewport is set just like that

Comment: And your `#slideshow`, does it has a `max-width`?

Comment: As it works on desktop (and they has their screen size), and a tablet believe the site is 8000px, then somewhere it finds that value and adjust its size. Double check your css + meta.

Comment: slideshow is inside a .col-940 div, so it has max width of 940px; the slideshow itself sized fine, its the background image  (almost like a banner) that needs to extend the full width of the viewport

Comment: To know more you need to post a fiddle or a link we can look at.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7s44S/13/    the image of the lawyer being the slideshow... if you load that fiddle on mobile/tablet and scroll horizontally you will see the issue. on an actual site and not a fiddle the screen is zoomed out so that that entire 8000px fits in the window

Comment: fiddle made, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not find an answer so I had to redo the base structure of the theme, and do it the "right" way